# Launch a shortcut on the lock screen of an iPhone in iOS 16 without opening the Shortcuts app

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, shortcuts-app, lockscreen

In the new iOS 16, it's possible to launch shortcuts directly from the lock screen. Unfortunately, my iPhone 8 isn't supported by this version. After a bit of research, I came across quite a few apps that provide this feature. Out of them, I picked LockFlow. While it does work, it's quite a hassle that it first opens its own app (after unlocking the iPhone via TouchID), then opens the Shortcuts app, and only then runs the desired shortcut.

Is there a way to launch a shortcut without opening these apps?